# Revoke client X509 certificate

Tags: x509

I have ASP.NET web service on windows server 2003. I have own certificate authority. I use own client certificate on authentification in web service.
I make client certificate. I call web service, everything is ok. Then I revoke this certificate in certification authority. Certificate is in Revoked certificate. 
I call web service with this certificate, but web service verify this certificate as good, but this certificate is between revoked. I don't know why? Anybody help me please?

I use this method on verify certificate.

X509Certificate2.Verify Method

I don't get any exception, certificate is between revoked, but web service verify this certificate as good.

to klausbyskov:
Thank you. So I try  this :

```
    public void CreateUser(X509Certificate2 cert)
    {

        ServicePointManager.UseNagleAlgorithm = true;
        ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
        ServicePointManager.CheckCertificateRevocationList = true;
        ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit =    ServicePointManager.DefaultPersistentConnectionLimit;

        if (VefiryCert(cert))
        {
          //...
        }
   }
```

But the revoked certificate is still verify as good

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `CheckCertificateRevocationList` property of the [`ServicePointManager`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager_members.aspx) class to `true` before calling `Verify()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting it in applications config file:

Maybe that helps..

Answer (score 0):

Validation is based on various factors.

Does the certificate have Certificate Revocation List Distribution Point (CDP) Extensions and is the CRL accessible? (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-4.2.1.13)

NOTE: CRLs are cached!

The only way to check the validity without almost any delay would be asking the CA itself. But I wouldn't consider this as an option.

For what you are trying to achieve the online responder protocol has been introduced (http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2560.txt).

Does the certificate have an AIA OCSP Extension and do you have an OCSP Responder set up? What are the triggers/intervals of OCSP (as its data is also a CRL)?